# Cant change the colour of the child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup:

I am using Piklor, a cooler picker https://github.com/jillix/piklor.js/

It is initialised by:
header = pk.getElm(".selected-icon p")

and the colour attributes are assigned here:

```
    header.style.color = col;
```

However, the above doesn't work. Am I targeting the p tag right? The class of the p tag changes pragmatically in my scrip, so I can't really use the class name and can only refer to it by the parent element.

If I target ".selected-icon" (without the p tag) and with a backgroundColor, e.g. header.style.backgroundColor = col; it seems to work, but not the colour of the p tag.

```js
(function (root) {

    /**
     * Piklor
     * Creates a new `Piklor` instance.
     *
     * @name Piklor
     * @function
     * @param {String|Element} sel The element where the color picker will live.
     * @param {Array} colors An array of strings representing colors.
     * @param {Object} options An object containing the following fields:
     *
     *  - `open` (String|Element): The HTML element or query selector which will open the picker.
     *  - `openEvent` (String): The open event (default: `"click"`).
     *  - `style` (Object): Some style options:
     *    - `display` (String): The display value when the picker is opened (default: `"block"`).
     *  - `template` (String): The color item template. The `{color}` snippet will be replaced
     *    with the color value (default: `"<div data-col=\"{color}\" style=\"background-color: {color}\"></div>"`).
     *  - `autoclose` (Boolean): If `false`, the color picker will not be hided by default (default: `true`).
     *  - `closeOnBlur` (Boolean): If `true`, the color picker will be closed when clicked outside of it (default: `false`).
     *
     * @return {Piklor} The `Piklor` instance.
     */
    function Piklor(sel, colors, options) {
        var self = this;
        options = options || {};
        options.open = self.getElm(options.open);
        options.openEvent = options.openEvent || "click";
        options.style = Object(options.style);
        options.style.display = options.style.display || "block";
        options.closeOnBlur = options.closeOnBlur || false;
        options.template = options.template || "<div data-col=\"{color}\" style=\"background-color: {color}\"></div>";
        self.elm = self.getElm(sel);
        self.cbs = [];
        self.isOpen = true;
        self.colors = colors;
        self.options = options;
        self.render();

        // Handle the open element and event.
        if (options.open) {
            options.open.addEventListener(options.openEvent, function (ev) {
                self.isOpen ? self.close() : self.open();
            });
        }

        // Click on colors
        self.elm.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
            var col = ev.target.getAttribute("data-col");
            if (!col) { return; }
            self.set(col);
            self.close();
        });
        
        if (options.closeOnBlur) {
          window.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
              // check if we didn't click 'open' and 'color pallete' elements
              if (ev.target != options.open && ev.target != self.elm && self.isOpen) {
                self.close();
              }
          });
        }

        if (options.autoclose !== false) {
            self.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * getElm
     * Finds the HTML element.
     *
     * @name getElm
     * @function
     * @param {String|Element} el The HTML element or query selector.
     * @return {HTMLElement} The selected HTML element.
     */
    Piklor.prototype.getElm = function (el) {
        if (typeof el === "string") {
            return document.querySelector(el);
        }
        return el;
    };

    /**
     * render
     * Renders the colors.
     *
     * @name render
     * @function
     */
    Piklor.prototype.render = function () {
        var self = this
          , html = ""
          ;

        self.colors.forEach(function (c) {
            html += self.options.template.replace(/\{color\}/g, c);
        });

        self.elm.innerHTML = html;
    };

    /**
     * close
     * Closes the color picker.
     *
     * @name close
     * @function
     */
    Piklor.prototype.close = function () {
        this.elm.style.display = "none";
        this.isOpen = false;
    };

    /**
     * open
     * Opens the color picker.
     *
     * @name open
     * @function
     */
    Piklor.prototype.open = function () {
        this.elm.style.display = this.options.style.display;
        this.isOpen = true;
    };

    /**
     * colorChosen
     * Adds a new callback in the colorChosen callback buffer.
     *
     * @name colorChosen
     * @function
     * @param {Function} cb The callback function called with the selected color.
     */
    Piklor.prototype.colorChosen = function (cb) {
        this.cbs.push(cb);
    };

    /**
     * set
     * Sets the color picker color.
     *
     * @name set
     * @function
     * @param {String} c The color to set.
     * @param {Boolean} p If `false`, the `colorChosen` callbacks will not be called.
     */
    Piklor.prototype.set = function (c, p) {
        var self = this;
        self.color = c;
        if (p === false) { return; }
        self.cbs.forEach(function (cb) {
            cb.call(self, c);
        });
    };

    root.Piklor = Piklor;
})(this);

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var pk = new Piklor(".color-picker", [
            "#1abc9c"
          , "#2ecc71"
          , "#3498db"
          , "#9b59b6"
          , "#34495e"
          , "#16a085"
          , "#27ae60"
          , "#2980b9"
          , "#8e44ad"
          , "#2c3e50"
          , "#f1c40f"
          , "#e67e22"
          , "#e74c3c"
          , "#ecf0f1"
          , "#95a5a6"
          , "#f39c12"
          , "#d35400"
          , "#c0392b"
          , "#bdc3c7"
          , "#7f8c8d"
        ], {
            open: ".picker-wrapper .btn"
        })
      , wrapperEl = pk.getElm(".picker-wrapper")
      , header = pk.getElm(".selected-icon p")
      , footer = pk.getElm("footer")
      ;

    pk.colorChosen(function (col) {
        wrapperEl.style.backgroundColor = col;
        header.style.backgroundColor = col;
        footer.style.backgroundColor = col;
    });
});
```

```css
/* picker */
.color-picker {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.6);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.color-picker > div {
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.picker-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
}

.color-picker > div:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="selected-icon"><p class="icon-eight">Hello</i></span>
<div class="picker-wrapper">
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Select color</button>
                        <div class="color-picker">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: So what are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the color of the text to change, without using the class name "icon-eight"?

Comment: @Noah yes, indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. If that is the case, your issue is the p tag is not closed.

`<span class="selected-icon"><p class="icon-eight">Hello</i></span>`

You have an "i" tag trying to close the leading "p" tag. Change that and you should be good to go.

Also change

```
header.style.backgroundColor = col;
```

To

```
  header.style.color = col;
```

To achieve the desired result.